# Modificar un archivo JSON con $getJSON (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tengo el siguiente código:

```
 $.getJSON("config.json", function(json) {
        json.Lanzador.nombre = nombre;
 });
```

donde:
nombre: es el valor que quiero asignar;
config.json: es el archivo json que quiero modificar
json.Lanzador.nombre: sigue la estructura del archivo json.

```
{
    "nombre1":[..],
    "Lanzador": {
        "id": 0,
        "nombre":"valor"
     }
}
```

Quiero modificar el archivo json pero nunca se actualiza.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Te da algún error por consola? ¿Cómo es la estructura dentro de tu fichero? Por favor, especifica un poco más cual es tu problema.

Comment: por consola no me da ningún error. Ya he añadido la estructura del JSON.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene `nombre1`? ¿Varios nombres?

Comment: Contiene varios objetos. El caso que para leer los datos, la sentencia de arriba (json.Lanzador.nombre) si me funciona para visualizar el nombre. Pero en el momento de modificarlo no lo modifica

Comment: ¿Desde donde intentas visualizar los cambios después? ¿Desde dentro de la función?

Comment: o con otro $getJSON o mirando directamente en el archivo JSON.

Comment: No puedes. El hecho de que puedas **parsear la data a un objecto javascript** no significa que puedes modificar el archivo con solo cambiar el valor de una propiedad. Para lograr eso necesitas utilizar una aplicacion del lado del servidor para que te modifique el archivo.

Comment: @Einer vale, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si el JSON está en el servidor, como ya ha dicho @Einer, es imposible modificarlo desde el cliente. Tendrías que crear un script que lance un archivo PHP vía Ajax el cual se encargue de modificar el archivo y devolvértelo modificado. Otra cosa que podrías hacer sería, si el JSON es para uso particular y debe quedar intacto en el servidor, traerlo, modificarlo y guardarlos del lado del cliente. En ese caso estarías haciendo una copia local de tu JSON remoto. Esa copia sí podrías manipularla a tu gusto.